# RabbitMQ overflow queue to disk

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ with limited amount of RAM. If publishers and consumers online, it's all ok, but when need do restart consumer, RabbitMQ fill the memory and block publishers. When publishers is blocked, it will  fast eat RAM. 
How to confiurate RabbitMQ to overflow queue to disk, is RAM is fully filled?

Comment: do you have plenty of disk space.  If you do not have a large enough amount of free disk space it could be that that is blocking.  Could you edit your question to give and indication of how much RAM and free disk space you have please.

Comment: Free RAM about 2G for RabbitMQ, on disk storage about 100Gb

Comment: Are you pushing a large amount of persistent messages to the queues?  I have a set up with 2G RAM and only 3G HDD space and it works fine.  Not saying that you shouldnt have a problem just that we may need to investigate further

Comment: It's not answer. I telling that need put data to disk, if memory is ended and don't block connections

Answer (score 0):

It might help to make use of the Time-To-Live Extensions. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl and set an expiration for messages.